# Gradle build not working with lombok Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-8, lombok

I have gradle project which has lombok jar ,i have added the below dependency in gradle,  Gradle version : 4.5.1

```
compileOnly group:'org.projectlombok',name:'lombok', version: '1.16.20'
```

gradle build in command prompts not working

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: getting compilation error cannot find the symbol  setter method and getter methods are not finding , due to the lombok jar where we will not give the setter getter just will provide @Data annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Able to resolve the issue :) The spring rest api is like `public Department getEmployeesDepartmet(@Pathvariabel(ID) int id , @Pathvariable(employeId)int employeeID)`

here ID and employeeID was string constant due to this getting compiler error int cannot convert to String just removed the constant and added string variables in path variable –

Answer (score 0):

For me the expression you referenced is working correctly. Can you provide more detailed description of the error you observed. To display more detailed trace on what went wrong use the '**--stacktrace**' command line switch, for example:

```
.\gradlew --stacktrace assemble
```

Is the command line gradle gives you the compile error message? Or are you using Android Studio if so perhaps you forgot to setup lombok as a annotation Processor agent, see: https://projectlombok.org/setup/android and *File > Other Settings > Default Settings... > Build, Execution, Development > Compiler > Annotation Processors > Enable annotation processing*.

Comment: Thanks @Istvan, its Java Based Spring Boot Project when i do gradle build  Istvan `TestService.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        resource.setTopic(topic);
                ^
  symbol:   method setTopic(Topic)
  location: variable resource of type Measure
User\dd\exception\handler\RestR
esponseEntityExceptionHandler.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
                return ApiError.builder()
                               ^
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class ApiError`
these errors are lombok setter and builder methods

Comment: Finally Able to resolve the issue :) The spring rest api   is like `public Department getEmployeesDepartmet(@Pathvariabel(ID) int id , @Pathvariable(employeId) in employeeID)  here ID and employeeID was string constant ` due to this getting compiler error int cannot convert to String just removed the constant and added string varaiibles in pathvariable